# Can a template parameter name of a function template be used more than once in the function parameter list?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, parameter-passing, 2d

I made this function for specific use on 2d arrays of quadratic shape : `rowLength == colLength`

If you pass a rectangular array the function will fail because the implementation doesn't fit for rectangular shapes : `rowLength != colLength`

Using only one template ensures the array is quadratic. Let the compiler warn you against rectangular because the parameters have to be equals to "satisfy" the template system.

I know there would be different solutions but this one do exactly what I wished.

```
template <std::size_t sideLength>
void functionForQuadraticArrayOnly( const int( &arr )[ sideLength ][ sideLength ] )
{// body....}
```

Question :
Is this template usage correct? Is it Undefined Behaviour or something else ?

Comment: Looks okay, after formatting your code block.

Comment: Why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: Thank you @mch !

Comment: @Alan Birtles I'm not sure because sideLength parameter is declared once in the template but used twice in the array "recognition" so I think it will be overridden in some way, I'm not sure if it's just a case it works or is a regular use.

Comment: It is a very common thing to use a template twice, for example if you want to get 2 parameters of the same type `template <class T> void foo(T a, T b)` or return the same type as a parameter `template <class T> T foo(T a)`. You can also use it in the function body to declare a variable...

Comment: So for example if I pass an array of size 5x5 it recognizes a type size_t(5) from rows and a type size_t(5) from cols and it's ok because they are like of the same type T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here is safe.   However, it would be good to be aware of one special case mentioned in the standard .

Consider the following example:

```
typedef int N;
template<N X, typename N, template<N Y> class T> struct A;
```

Here, `X` is a non-type template parameter of type `int` and `Y` is a non-type template parameter of the same type as the second template parameter of `A`.

Note that `Y` is a **not** a non-type template parameter of type `int` because the template parameter `N` hides the `N` of the `typedef`.

This is as per [**`[basic.scope.temp]/4]`**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.temp#4) which states:

> The declarative region of the name of a template parameter is nested within the immediately-enclosing declarative region. [ Note: As a result, a template-parameter hides any entity with the same name in an enclosing scope]